# TwoCircles Dataset

Tags: data-request

I am analysing an article dealing with: "Semi-supervised Graph Clustering: A Kernel Approach" I need to reproduce figure 1 on page 7. http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/inderjit/public_papers/kernel_icml.pdf

I didn't find the dataset of two circles? Could you please help me find that?

Comment: Do you need the exact same dataset, or just something similar?

Comment: Just something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could generate a similar dataset in Python using scikit-learn's  [make_circles](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_circles.html) function.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_samples = 400

samples, labels = make_circles(n_samples=n_samples, factor=.3, noise=.05)

bluecircle = samples[labels==0]
redcircle  = samples[labels==1]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(bluecircle[:, 0], bluecircle[:, 1], c='b', marker='o', s=10)
plt.scatter(redcircle[:, 0], redcircle[:, 1], c='r', marker='+', s=30)
plt.show()
```

[image]

In Matlab you could could generate the dataset with something like:

```
n = 200;
step = 1/n;
radius = 0.5;
ratio = 0.4;

ang=0:step:2*pi; 
xp=radius*cos(ang);
yp=radius*sin(ang);

hold on;

% blue circle
idx = randsample(length([xp;yp]),n);
bluex = xp+(rand(length(xp),1)*radius/10)';
bluey = yp+(rand(length(yp),1)*radius/10)';
scatter(bluex(:,idx),bluey(:,idx),'b','o');

% red circle
idx = randsample(length([xp;yp]),n);
redx = ratio*xp+(rand(length(xp),1)*radius/10)';
redy = ratio*yp+(rand(length(yp),1)*radius/10)';
scatter(redx(:,idx),redy(:,idx),'r','+');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot, how could I generate the same graph with Matlab ?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example in Matlab